# How to force the (default)scrollbar to move with easing(specially in chrome)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scrollbar

What I'm trying to achieve is that I want to force the DEFAULT scrollbar to move up and down with an easing animation.something like [this plugin](http://jsfiddle.net/7ZVb7/1383/)

or something really close to new firefox's Scrollbar(it scrolls with ease and not suddenly like chrome's or windows' default)

I tried many things,but none of them worked to perfection.for example I wanted to inspire from [this tutorial](http://jsfiddle.net/7ZVb7/1383/), but as soon as I change the `overflow` property to `auto`,(to give the container a scrollbar), everything will go nuts!(you can try for yourself to see what I mean).I even tried the code below,but then again,it has its own problems:

THE HTML:

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="test"></div>
        <div class="test"></div>
        <div class="test"></div>
        <div class="test"></div>
</div>
```

THE CSS:

```
.container {
    width: 300px;
    height: 700px;
    background-color: red;
    overflow: scroll;
}

.test {
    width: 200px;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: blue;
    margin: 5px 0 5px 0;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
```

THE JAVASCRIPT:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('.container').mousewheel(function (e) {
            var cp = $(this).scrollTop();
            var deltaY = e.deltaY;
            var deltaFactor = e.deltaFactor;
            var sd = cp + (deltaFactor * (-deltaY));
            $(this).stop().animate({ scrollTop: sd });
        });
});
```

As I said I don't want to use external plugins(like niceScroll or costume-scrollbar-pugin).And to emphasize,I want the scrollbar to behave like firefox's scrollbar

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered something like [this?](https://github.com/fatlinesofcode/jquery.smoothwheel) (not sure if this is exactly what you are looking for though...)

[Here](http://fatlinesofcode.github.io/jquery.smoothwheel/demo/smoothwheel.html) is a demo of the script in use

**EDIT**

Removed as it was no longer in use and was full of bugs

Comment: It actually is close to what I am looking for.But the problem is I want to use it on the `body` element and this plugin doesn't work with `body` :(

Comment: Have you tried applying it to the `body` element? Chances are it will work

Comment: unfortunately it doesn't work with the body element :(